# php numbers: assert( 1.0 < 2.0 )

Tags: php, numbers, assert

How can this

```
<?php
assert( 1.0 < 2.0 );
?>
```

result in

Warning: assert() [function.assert]: Assertion failed in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\test.php on line 2

Edit: depending on the file I put this code in, `1.0 < 2.0` evaluates to `false` or `true`.

Comment: Sure you haven't typed o instead of 0?

Comment: Off hand, I'd say it can't... That assert certainly doesn't fail in any of the myriad versions of PHP I have available.

Comment: Wait, you're saying that the code `1.0 < 2.0` evaluates to false under some condition?  Really?  Can you please post EXACT code when it evaluates to false (and how you know)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: it gets worse.  It's volatile...

Comment: Huh?  What's the smallest code that you can reproduce it with?  is `<?php var_dump(1.0 < 2.0);` enough?  What version of PHP are you running,and how are you running it (Apache module, command line, etc)?  Anything in the logs?  Debug build?

Comment: @ircmaxell: I'm running it via wamp 2.2.11 with PHP 5.30 on windows7.  I'm starting to blame my source code editor (komodo) now.  It's not a php issue, I'm quite sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing it as a string instead. :)

assert("1.0 < 2.0");

Comment: like in `assert( "hello world" )`?  The thing is, actually the condition `1.0 < 2.0` returns false.

Comment: The string you pass to assert is parsed and executed as a php code and then the result is asserted. This is written here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php

Comment: `assert()` will evaluate the string you pass it.  Generally passing a string is better practice; assert can show you the test that failed, and when assert checking is off the code isn't evaluated saving some overhead in production.

Comment: thaks for the quote-tip.  It's very useful.